Difference Between Knowledge Source and Data Source
I'm trying to build a custom copilot. I've added several knowledge sources, but when I enable "Search only selected sources" in a "Create generative answers" node it does nothing. If I add links into the data sources under classic data, then it magically works.
Can somebody explain the difference between a knowledge source and data source, and why gen ai can use one and not the other?

AI can use both. Knowledge sources use Microsoft Graph, and data sources use SharePoint Search. By default, you can input a filename, or part of a filename and receive a summary of the file and a reference link to it. This works for both source types. If you want to query a file based on metadata, you should first ensure that that the crawled property is mapped to a refinable string. Then, create a PA Flow that uses the SharePoint REST API to retrieve all files that match your query. After, return a variable of the filenames separated by comma and input it into gen ai. Use knowledge sources.
